# Changing Grails SDK in IntelliJ IDEA Doesn't Work on Plugin Modules

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

IDEA 11.1.2

I have a Grails app I need to upgrade.  The application consists of several modules. One being the application and a few others being plugins.  I right clicked on the application and went to Grails -> Change SDK Version.  I chose the version I wanted, then IDEA asked me if I wanted to upgrade the application.  Clicked yes and all was good.

I've been trying to do the same thing on the plugin modules.  IDEA never asks if I want to upgrade and it doesn't appear to change the SDK.  If I upgrade the modules from the command line, when I come back to IDEA, it thinks there is a version mismatch and automatically downgrades me without even asking.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me in this IDEA version. Make sure that you change Grails version in application.properties of all plugins:

```
app.grails.version=2.1.0
```

Then right-click on every module (plugin), Grails, Change SDK version. It should be changed already.

Comment: Obviously, I did that since I said I upgraded from the command line.  "It works for me" is not really an answer, is it?  But thanks.

Comment: Works for me is a good answer since I've showed you two steps to reproduce my case that has worked. I can only recommend to restart IDEA, maybe it will pick up changes correctly.

Comment: File>invalidate caches ... seems to help for me running IJ on W7 ... I 'think' IJ chokes somewhere :: Ivy?  Groovy?

Answer (score 3):

Have exactly same problem - app + plugins wich requires different SDK (for testing).

After some investigation found that it's an IntelliJ IDEA bug [IDEA-114418](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114418). So, I think, it will be good if you'll vote for this bug there too.

Comment: Having the same problem, voting for the bug

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same bug. I took extreme measures to rectify it.

I deleted the old grails from the Global Libraries. Go to `file>Project Structure > Global Libraries` . It should complain that this is used by a module.

Then I had to add grails framework support, but added the new one.

Comment: In addition, I closed the IDE and reopened to get it to prompt for Grails SDK